# The bird with no name (For mature people only)

Tags: riddle

***What bird can't fly or run very fast, and is different shades of brown, all at the same time?***

If you're a man, stand on top of a tree, look down, put the two things you see together, and you might just think maybe the answer has to do with a part of you.

---

#### Hints (from the comments below):

**Hint 1**

> **American**.  It's just a word but it's a part of the answer.  I think that part might be hard to guess because the riddle doesn't have any clues to that part.  The rest of the answer has a clue in the riddle.

**Hint 2**

> Multiple shades of brown all at once could mean a variety of different kinds of brown feathers on one bird.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> An [American Woodcock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_woodcock)

because

> It's brown and has the slowest recorded flying speed of any bird.
>  A tree is made of wood, and wood is a slang term for an erection, which ties in to the 2nd half of the name of the bird.
>  A cock is slang for a penis, which a (naked) man would see when looking down from the top of a tree.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is:

> Woody Woodpecker

A man looking down would see the second word...  The first half is the content of the tree and second is a common slang for a male part.

The answer is not know for running or flying fast.  The content as mentioned has varying shades of brown.

Comment: Hi! I added spoiler markup to your answer. Be warned, though: a lot of the time, people around here want to see a reason for the answer, so you might want to flesh it out a little.

Comment: That's not brown

Comment: @Raystafarian but if you remove one word from this answer, it fits.

Comment: So i kinda was just trying to make a riddle for fun and see if it was any good and thats why i made it also i would like to add a hint that might help and my hint is Acerican its just a word but it's a part or the answer because i think that part might be hard to guess because the riddle dosent have any clues to that part the the rest of the answer has a clue in the riddle.

Comment: I would also like to add in that multapile shades of brown all at wonce could mean a variaty or diffrent kinds of brown feathers on one bird.

Comment: @conner If you want to add hints/comments regarding the solution, you should probably edit the question itself, so that everyone is more likely to see them.  Click on "edit" just under the tags listed below your question.  (Also, I think you meant "American", not "Acerican" in your comment above.)